# Different functionality depending on the selected role in telegram bot. How to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot,which at the very beginning asks user to choose a role. Depending on the selected role, some requests and functions are available or inaccessible to him. How can one create such action scenarios and limit them from each other?

Comment: in which variable do you save the role selection made by the user ?

Comment: I use text variables as it goes like an awnser to a question

Comment: it'd be really useful if you may share a piece of code, or an example of what is troubling you. all this sounds quite vague, so there is the risk any answer might be too vague as well.